# Why are the document getter functions being reset?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a small chrome extension to help find where cookies are using in websites. The extension is SUPPOSE to work by setting the getter method for the cookie on the document.
Like so:

```
document.__defineGetter__('cookie',function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

When manually put into chrome's javascript console on a website and then trying to access a cookie (simply typing "`document.cookie`") it results in the expected behavior where it will pop up the test prompt.

However when I put this into a chrome extension and have it load before the rest of the page it will fail to work.

Here is the manifest.json (I was just using soundcloud as a test website):

```
{
    "name": "Cookie Auditor",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "An extension to help examine where cookies are being used in websites.",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.soundcloud.com/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is the content.js:

```
console.log(document.location);
document.__defineGetter__('cookie',function(){
    alert("test");
});
console.log(document.__lookupGetter__('cookie'));
```

When attempting to manually trigger it (`document.cookie`) it simply returns the normal value and fails to execute the javascript. When it failed to work here I put in the checks for the document location to make sure it was executing on the right domain and was even loading at all.
The weird part is when you load the page with this extension it will print out that it is on the right domain and it even shows that the cookie getter method was overwritten correctly (it print the function in the console).
However when you lookup the getter method it has been reset (`document.__lookupGetter__('cookie')`).

My last thought was that it was being reset sometime between my content.js script running and the rest of the page initializing. However when I change the "run_at" field in the manifest.json file to "document_end" in an attempt to make it run later and potentually after any sort of re initialization of the document then soundcloud's stuff will start printing on the console showing that it has properly loaded the page however my script still fails to have made an effect.

EDIT: Before it is suggested. I can't use chrome's cookie API because it doesn't provide a way of actually listening to when a cookie is retrieved which is the main thing I care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I found out why it was failing. Chrome extensions are executed in their own javascript space but with the same DOM as the site they run on. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment. This causes them to have seperate global variables and thus my script's attempts to change them would only affect itself. For anyone looking at how to get around this limitation all you have to do is add a script tag with your code onto the document from your extension.